# iText Chinese punctuation at the beginning of line

Tags: itext

Do you know how to resolve the problem when one line is full, then the Chinese punctuations will be placed at the beginning of next line as shown in (1)? In fact we hope the punctuations to be placed at the end of each line as shown in (2).

（1）

**你好你好**

**,你好你好**

（2）

**你好你好,**

**你好你好**

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Comment: You may check my code at:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/42417087/7611210 I think it'll work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are placing a space between the last char and the punctuation and that is a split point. The simplest way is to remove the space before the puntuation and add it after. Other option is to replace the space with a non breaking space \u00a0 to avoid the split at that point.

Comment: Hi Paulo, Than you! In fact I did not place space between the last char and the punctuation. By default, in iText, if one line (let's mark it as line A) is full, and the last char is punctuation, then the punctuation will be placed at the beginning of next line (let's mark it as line B). I try to resolve this problem by the method that if the punctuation was placed at the beginning of line B, then I move the last chinese character from line A to the beginning of line B; however, by this method, there will be a space at the end of line A, I do not know how to make line A align justified.

Comment: In my first post, it seems as if there is a space at the end of the first line of (1), just because I was not allowed to post image to demonstrate the problem, in fact the first line and second line will be aligned justified.

Comment: There's no split at punctuation in the default split. If you have a line with no split points, like spaces, the split will be done by width alone and the split point can be anywhere.

Comment: Hi Paulo, thank you for your reply! That's exact the reason caused the problem of placing punctuation at the beginning of lines. Because there is no split (space) between chinese characters, and there is no split (space) between chinese character and chinese punctuation. Do you have any solutions for this problem?

Comment: The solution is to set your split rules. Use `DefaultSplitCharacter` to do that.

Comment: hi Paulo, could you please give me some detail instructions with demo codes? Thank you very much!