# How to fix CJK punctuation at the beginning of line in iText7/iText7.pdfhtml

Tags: .net, itext7

I have encountered this problem when using iText7/iText7.pdfhtml to convert HTML string into PDF file. I had found some similar questions like:

- [How to fix orphaned punctuation in iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35783445/how-to-fix-orphaned-punctuation-in-itext)
- [iText Chinese punctuation at the beginning of line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33929357/itext-chinese-punctuation-at-the-beginning-of-line)

But these questions' solution is for iText5, I have tried these solutions at my application but failed at last. My code goes like this:

```
IList<IElement> elements = HtmlConverter.ConvertToElements(pdfHtmlString, properties);
Document document = new Document(pdfDoc);
CJKSplitCharacters splitCharacters = new CJKSplitCharacters();
document.SetFontProvider(fp);
document.SetSplitCharacters(splitCharacters);
document.SetProperty(Property.SPLIT_CHARACTERS, splitCharacters);
foreach (IElement e in elements)
{
     try
     {
          document.Add((AreaBreak)e);
     }
     catch
     {
          document.Add((IBlockElement)e);
     }
}
```

Code for `CJKSplitCharacters`:

```
public class CJKSplitCharacters : ISplitCharacters
{
    // line of text cannot start or end with this character
    static char u2060 = '\u2060';   //       - ZERO WIDTH NO BREAK SPACE

    // a line of text cannot start with any following characters in NOT_BEGIN_CHARACTERS[]
    static char[] NOT_BEGIN_CHARACTERS = new char[]{u30fb, u2022, uff65, u300d, uff09, u0021, u0025, u0029, u002c,
      u002e, u003f, u005d, u007d, uff61, uff63, uff64, uff67, uff68, uff69, uff6a, uff6b, uff6c, uff6d, uff6e,
      uff6f, uff70, uff9e, uff9f, u3001, u3002, uff0c, uff0e, uff1a, uff1b, uff1f, uff01, u309b, u309c, u30fd,
      u30fe, u309d, u309e, u3005, u30fc, u2019, u201d, u3015, uff3d, uff5d, u3009, u300b, u300f, u3011, u00b0,
      u2032, u2033, u2103, u00a2, uff05, u2030, u3041, u3043, u3045, u3047, u3049, u3063, u3083, u3085, u3087,
      u308e, u30a1, u30a3, u30a5, u30a7, u30a9, u30c3, u30e3, u30e5, u30e7, u30ee, u30f5, u30f6, u2060};

    // a line of text cannot end with any following characters in NOT_ENDING_CHARACTERS[]
    static char[] NOT_ENDING_CHARACTERS = new char[]{u0024, u0028, u005b, u007b, u00a3, u00a5, u201c, u2018, u3008,
      u300a, u300c, u300e, u3010, u3014, uff62, uff08, uff3b, uff5b, uffe5, uff04, u2060};

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text"></param>
    /// <param name="glyphPos"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool IsSplitCharacter(GlyphLine text, int glyphPos)
    {
        if (!text.Get(glyphPos).HasValidUnicode())
        {
            return false;
        }
        int charCode = text.Get(glyphPos).GetUnicode();

        if (NOT_BEGIN_CHARACTERS.Contains((char)charCode))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return new DefaultSplitCharacters().IsSplitCharacter(text, glyphPos);
    }
```

My source code is here: [Source Code](https://github.com/RyougiChan/HTML2PDF-netcore)

My problem as follows:

[image: CJK punctuation problem in iText7/iText7.pdfhtml]

#### Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Comment: Thanks for the reproducible project that you posted on GitHub. Tip for the future: post minimal reproducible sample, including the string/HTML that you are trying to convert. E.g. for me there is no chance I can type those glyphs manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is in `IsSplitCharacter` method implementation. You are not using `NOT_ENDING_CHARACTERS` and are only using `NOT_BEGIN_CHARACTERS`.

Although I cannot reproduce your sample due to lack of source string data (which means I haven't tested my approach), I think the way you should implement the method in question is the following:

```
public bool IsSplitCharacter(GlyphLine text, int glyphPos)
{
    if (!text.Get(glyphPos).HasValidUnicode())
    {
        return false;
    }
    int charCode = text.Get(glyphPos).GetUnicode();

    if (NOT_ENDING_CHARACTERS.Contains((char)charCode))
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Look ahead for the next non-whitespace character and check it not to be in NOT_BEGIN_CHARACTERS list
    for (int i = 1; glyphPos + i < text.end; i++)
    {
        if (!text.Get(glyphPos + i).HasValidUnicode())
        {
            break;
        }
        if (!TextUtil.isSpaceOrWhitespace(text.Get(glyphPos + i)))
        {
            if (NOT_BEGIN_CHARACTERS.Contains(text.Get(glyphPos + i).GetUnicode()))
            {
                return false;
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    return new DefaultSplitCharacters().IsSplitCharacter(text, glyphPos);
}
```

Please also note that your implementation is not very efficient and you should replace char arrays with HashSets to speed up the `Contains` lookup which is now linear with respect to sizes of your arrays. Also instead of creating `DefaultSplitCharacters` instance each time in `IsSplitCharacter`, you should create it once as a field in your `CJKSplitCharacters` class and reuse it.

Comment: Hi @AlexeySubach, thanks for your answer here. I have tried your solution here and found that it worked well.  It seems that the lack of `NOT_ENDING_CHARACTERS` causes this problem. And thanks for your tips here also, I will pay attention to these tips in the future. Best wishes!